# Regex to find&replace movie names python

Tags: python, regex, twitter, replace

I've been working on tweets about different movies (using the Twitter Search API) and now I wanted to replace the match by a fixed string.

I've been struggling with "XMen Apocalypse" because there are many ways to find this on tweets.
I looked for **"XMen Apocalypse"**, **"X-Men Apocalypse"**, **"X Men Apocalypse"**, **"XMen"**, **"X-Men"**, **"X Men"** and it retrived me matches that also includes **"@xmenmovie"**, **"#xmen"**, **"x-men: apocalypse"**, etc...

This is the regex that I have:

```
xmen_regex = re.compile("(((#)x[\-]?men:?(apocalypse)?)|(x[\-]? ?men[:]?[ ]?(apocalypse)?))")
def re_place_moviename(text, compiled_regex):
    return re.sub(compiled_regex, "MOVIE_NAME", text.lower())
```

I have tested with [RegExr](http://regexr.com/), but still isn't accurate at some edge cases like: '#xmen blabla' -> replace -> '#MOVIE_NAME blabla' or 'MOVIE_NAMEblabla'.

So, there is a better way to do this? maybe compile different regex (on increasing length order (?)) and applying it separately?

*edit*

**Constrains (or summary):**

1. I want to find "x-men", "x men", "xmen"
2. All of 1 + " apocalypse"
3. All of 1 + ": apocalypse"
4. Also: "#xmen", "#x-men", "#xmenapocalypse", "#x-menapocalypse"
5. All musn't be a substring ("@xmenmovie" or "lovexmen perfect"), must contain at least 1 space at the begining and end of the expression.

*PS: Other movies are easier, but xmen and others like Rogue One there has many ways to expressed it and we want to catches the most of it.*

*PS1: I know that **\b** can help, but I couldn't understand how it works.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do the job:

```
(?:^|\s)#x[ -]?men:?\s?apocalypse\b
```

In case of replacement, if you want to keep the space before, use a capture group and put it in the replacement part:

```
(^|\s)#x[ -]?men:?\s?apocalypse\b
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:^|\s)    : non capture group, begining of string or a space
#           : #
x           : x
[ -]?       : optional space or dash
men         : men
:?          : optional semicolon
\s?         : optional space
apocalypse  : apocalypse
\b          : word boundary
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the same that I came up today. The problem, is that I'm using re.sub(regx, 'MOVIE') the "non capture group" it is still substituted. i.e. 'jaja #xmen jaja' -> jajaMOVIE jaja

Comment: @OmarMiranda:You could use a capture group `(^|\s)` and add it in the replacement part.

Answer (score 0):

This should work per your (vague) constraints:
`(?i)(?<![#@])x[- ]?men(?!:)( apocalypse)?`

- `(?i)` -- ignore case flag
- `(?<![#@])` -- no `#` or `@` before 'xmen'
- `[- ]?` -- optional `-` or
- `(?!:)` -- no colon after 'xmen'
- `( apocalypse)?` -- optional apocalypse string

---

**Edit**: Instead of requiring a space in front/behind, I think having a boundary (`\b`) would be more fitting, i.e. `(?i)\b(?<!@)(x[- ]?men:?\s?(?:apocalypse)?)\b` as 'xmen' may start the sentence.

Comment: Thanks! I added a summary, sorry for not being so specific the first time :)

Comment: I modify (?i)\b(?<!@)(#x[- ]?men:?\s?(?:apocalypse)?)\b, adding the '#', but \b thinks that # is a word separator, so it only match xmen on #xmen; and how I using re.sub(regx, 'MOVIE'), the result is #MOVIE. That's the reason why (?:^|\s) works better, as @Toto suggested.